# Mountain Biking Websites

Tags: mountain-bike

What mountain bike websites are available?

I would like recommendations of sites containing:

- news
- product reviews
- interesting articles
- photo reviews

An example of the kind of sites I am after is [PinkBike](http://www.pinkbike.com/).

Comment: You're asking for websites about mountain biking? Like, product reviews, forums, and the like?

Comment: Yes, it is. I'm more interested about product reviews, interesting articles, photo reporting, etc. updated every day

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Expanding on previous answer(s):

- [PinkBike](http://www.pinkbike.com) - THE mountain bike site
- [Dirt Rag](http://www.dirtragmag.com) - One of the oldest mountain bike magazines
- [Vital MTB](http://www.vitalmtb.com) - Another great source of new/reviews
- [Bike Rumor](http://www.bikerumor.com) - Mostly product previews/reviews

Comment: Vital MTB is a very cool site, I like it, Thanks!

Comment: Someone attempted to add "qomli.com" to the list. However, this site doesn't load and google doesn't know about it, so it may not yet be a widely accepted site (it may also be malware, so: warnings). I suggest that the editor put this site in a separate answer rather than attempting to edit an accepted answer.

Answer (score 5):

There are numerous websites for mountain biking, each tends to service a niche either geographically or as part of the spectrum of mountain biking. Some of the bigger sites are:

- [Mountain Bike Review (MTBR)](http://www.mtbr.com) - US site
- [SingleTrack](http://singletrackworld.com) - UK site
- [Bike Radar](http://bikeradar.com/mtb/) - large cycling site with big mountain bike section
- [NSMB](http://NSMB.com) - similar and related to [PinkBike](http://pinkbike.com) but focused on BC, Canada's North Shore

Answer (score 0):

German sites welcome?

- http://www.mtb-news.de
- http://www.bike-magazin.de

Regards Stefan